# Horizontal line appears in fullscreen mode

Tags: macos, fullscreen

I have an issue when entering fullscreen mode in any application on my MacBook Pro with OS X 10.7.3, a white horizontal line *always* appears at the top of the screen (as shown in the picture).

What is causing that? I've never had it before and I can't figure out what I've done to cause it. Anyone that got the same issue or know what's causing this?

[image]

Comment: I had this problem as well and it was Kaspersky for me, too. I force quit everything one by one to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have and programs running such as VMware or Virtual Box installed and running in Full Screen Mode in the background? It alsmost looks like a VM or remote desktop toolbar. Have any programs running that have tool bars such as pictured below.

[image: VMWare]

Comment: Ah! Thank you. Just remembered I recently installed Kaspersky Antivirus 2011 for Mac. I restarted the Kaspersky software and now the line is gone! Thanks! The funniest is that Kaspersky AV doesn't even have toolbar there...

Comment: I had an odd feeling that's what it was, I just couldn't put my finger on it...